# How to group stream of Map to Map<String, Map<String, String>>?

Tags: groovy, java-stream

I have stream of Map [name:name1, type:type1, desc:desc1, ordinal:1]. How to  convert/group (with Groovy) to Map>: Map(type1: Map (neme:name1, desc:desc1, ordinal:1)). 
Stream of Map

```
[name:productName,  type:IN, ordinal:1, description:desc]
[name:productName1,  type:IN, ordinal:2, description:desc]
[name:productName2,  type:OUT, ordinal:3, description:desc]
```

and I have get: Map:

```
IN: Map[
    [name:productName,  type:IN, ordinal:1, description:desc.], 
    [name:productName1,  type:IN, ordinal:2, description:desc.]]
OUT: Map[
    [name:productName2, type:OUT, ordinal:3, description:desc.]]
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have, and what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream.collect()` method with `Collectors.groupingBy { it.type }` to collect all elements as map of `type` key and value of list of elements. Consider the following example:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors
import java.util.stream.Stream

def input = Stream.of(
    [name: 'productName', type: 'IN', ordinal: 1, description: 'desc'],
    [name: 'productName1', type: 'IN', ordinal: 2, description: 'desc'],
    [name: 'productName2', type: 'OUT', ordinal: 3, description: 'desc'],
)

def result = input.collect(Collectors.groupingBy { it.type })

result.each { println it }
```

Output:

```
IN=[{name=productName, type=IN, ordinal=1, description=desc}, {name=productName1, type=IN, ordinal=2, description=desc}]
OUT=[{name=productName2, type=OUT, ordinal=3, description=desc}]
```

Alternatively, if your input is not a `Stream` but a `List`, you could use good old Groovy `Collection.groupBy()` that does the same effect:

```
def input2 = [[name: 'productName', type: 'IN', ordinal: 1, description: 'desc'],
              [name: 'productName1', type: 'IN', ordinal: 2, description: 'desc'],
              [name: 'productName2', type: 'OUT', ordinal: 3, description: 'desc']]

def result2 = input2.groupBy { it.type }

result2.each { println it }
```